# How to get section Header value From cell Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

In my DidselectRowAt method I have a cell that I get using

```
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SongCell
```

However Mutilating this cell causes issues considering the table view Im in has multiple section Headers like this :

[image]

How Can I tell what section header my cell has so when I change the image on the right to gray , other cells in the tableview dont change? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused. You must not change any cell's content directly; you must build a knowledge of the desired cell state into your model data and reload the cell, which will call `cellForRow`, which will then get the correct state from the model data and configure this cell accordingly.